# Iterating through all rows in R, removing those that fit criteria

Tags: r, row, dataframe

R data frame. It has about a dozen columns and 150 or so rows. I want to iterate through each row and remove it, under these two conditions

1. It's value in column 8 is undefined
2. The value for the row ABOVE it, in column 8 IS defined.

My code looks like this, but it keeps crashing. It's gotta be a dumb mistake, but I can't figure it out.

```
for (i in 2:nrow(newfile)){
    if (is.na(newfile[i,8]) && !is.na(newfile[(i-1),8]){ 
    newfile<-newfile[-i,]
    }
}
```

Obviously in this example, newfile is my dataframe.

The error I get

> Error in `[.data.frame`(newfile, -i, ) : object 'i' not found

Problem solved, but some test data if you guys wanted to muck around:

```
23  L8  29141078    744319  27165443
24  L8  27165443    NA  NA
25  L8  28357836    8293    25116398
26  L8  25116398    NA  NA
27  L8  28357836    21600   25116398
28  L8  25116398    NA  NA
29  L8  40929564    NA  NA
30  L8  40929564    NA  NA
31  L8  41917264    33234   39446503
32  L8  39446503    NA  NA
33  L8  41917264    33981   39446503
34  L8  39446503    NA  NA
```

Obviously a little modified here, so now you are comparing column 4 with the one above it (or you can use column 5, either way)

Comment: I think you need one more parenthesis on your if statement.

Comment: Question - if you have some rows where column 8 looks like `1,NA,NA,1`, do you want your output to be `1,NA,1` (with that being the second `NA`)? Or, do we go row-by-row, get up to row 2 (the first `NA`), remove it, go to (old) row 3 (the second `NA`) -- do we remove it? Because after removing row 2 we're left with `1,NA,1` and now the remaining `NA` satisfies your conditions, so we'd be left with `1,1`.

Comment: And, if that's the case, really iterating through, then this is just an instance of removing all NAs after the first non-NA.

Comment: mathematical coffee has the idea, sorry it wasn't clear. But I would want the output of 1, NA(.1), NA(.2), 1 to look like 1, NA(.2), 1

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're changing the data frame out from under yourself; the original evaluation of `nrow(newfile)` doesn't get updated as you go along (it would if you had a C-style loop `for (i=1; i<=nrow(newfile); i++)` ...).  In a `while` loop, on the other hand, the condition will get re-evaluated every time through the loop, so I think this will work.

```
i <- 2
while (i<=nrow(newfile)){
   if (is.na(newfile[i,8]) && !is.na(newfile[i-1,8])) { 
     newfile<-newfile[-i,]
   }
   i <- i+1
}
```

You didn't give us an easily reproducible answer (i.e. a test dataset with answers), so I'm not going to test this right now.

Careful thought (which I don't have time to give this at the moment) might lead to a non-iterative (and hence perhaps very much faster, if that matters) way to do this.

Comment: @user1177193, if this is the best answer to your question, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check box. Also consider voting-up any helpful answer. All of this is described in http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if I do this, I get

```
Error in if (is.na(newfile[i,8]) && !is.na(newfile[(i-1),8]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is because you're removing rows while you're iterating through them, so by the time you get to `nrow(newfile)` (which is the original number of rows, since the `nrow(newfile)` is evaluated once at the beginning of the foor loop), it may not exist any more because rows have been removed.

You can avoid looping altogether by constructing a logical index of which rows to keep (ie vector of length `nrow(newfile)` with `TRUE` if you want to keep the row and `FALSE` otherwise):

```
n <- nrow(newfile)
# first bit says "is the row NA (for rows 2:n)"
# second bit says "is the row above *not* NA (for rows 1:(n-1))
# the & finds rows satisfying *both* conditions (first row always gets kept)
toRemove <- c(FALSE,is.na(newfile[-1,8])) & c(FALSE,!is.na(newfile[-n,8]))
toKeep   <- !toRemove
newfile  <- newfile[toKeep,]
```

You could do it all in one line if that's your thing:

```
newfile <- newfile[ !(c(FALSE,is.na(newfile[-1,8])) & c(FALSE,!is.na(newfile[-nrow(newfile),8]))), ]
```

Comment: This was my first instinct, but I wonder if the process of removing rows actually changes the problem (i.e. if we remove row 5 then we have to compare old row 6 (now row 5) with row 4) ... this is why a test data set would be a good idea.  If I'm right one would have to do something like compute run-length encodings (rle) to find strings of `NA`s in column 8 ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. But it keeps NA values if the previous value is also NA.

```
#create some dummy data
newfile <- matrix(runif(800), ncol = 8)
newfile[rbinom(100, 1, 0.25) == 1, 8] <- NA
#the selection
newfile[-which(diff(is.na(newfile[, 8])) == 1) - 1, ]
```